# error on results for sql join

Tags: sql, join

I'm joining two tables and it appears that each payment is being associated to a payee once, I think this is because of a join.

Say I have an account with two payments on it, and two different payees. The data is contained in two tables

```
Payment: 35.00, Payee: Dave
Payment: 40.00, payee: Mark
```

**Table1**

```
PK, Payment, Account number

35.00
40.00
```

**Table2**

```
PK, Payee, Account number

Mark
Dave
```

Query:

```
select distinct C.Payment, B.Payee
from table1 C
join Table2 B on check.PK = trans.PK
where check.accountnumber like ''123456''
```

Results looks like this

```
35.00 Mark
35.00 Dave
40.00 Mark
40.00 Dave
```

Each name gets its own record of a payment which is inaccurate, any advice?

Comment: Why are you using distinct?

Comment: Based on your results, it looks like these tables have a Many to Many relationship, which means you either need to include more in your Join or us some type of cross walk table. Maybe a PaymentID?

Comment: your join is wrong and it resulted in  a cross join

Comment: Your relational model is off.  Your payee's should be related directly to the payments.  Then your payments are related to the accounts - thus linking the payees back to the account as well.  Your result set is due to the nature of payments being related to accounts, and payees related to accounts, but you have not shown how a payee is related to a given payment.

Comment: Learn some database design.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are just cross joining one table with another and getting back every possible combination of the two tables.  Try joining on accountnumber instead. The PK value in each table have nothing to do with each other and should not be joined on here.